# If Flash not supported, alternativ image

Tags: flash

If Flash not supported, i try to replace a img, it does with a "object" Tag but how it works with a "embed" Tag. If i replace the  Tag it works fine, but the animantion doesn't work any more.

```
<object id="myId" value="transparent" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"  width="640" height="400">
<param name="movie" value="/biel/flash.swf">
<param name="quality" value="high">
<PARAM NAME="swLiveConnect" VALUE="true">
<embed name="film" wmode="transparent" swliveconnect=true src="/biel/film.swf" quality=high  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="640" height="400">
         <p>alternativ content</p>
</object>
```

Here is my Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       src = "swfobject.js"
       swfobject.registerObject("myId", "9.0.0", "/expressInstall.swf");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this SWFObject generator: http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/swfobject/generator/

Choose 'dynamic publishing'.

Please note the `<div id="myAlternativeContent">` section in the generated code - that's where your image should go.